# Redirect to vue front end from larvel backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am integrating a payment gateway and all the code are executed by the backend.
I send a `post` request from the front end to backend and the payment process starts. After the payment is complete, I get a post request from the payment gateway to the backend with the payment info. Then I validate the payment and update the database.
The next step is to redirect the user to the `/success` route of my vuejs project.
Here is a scenario of my procedure.

- My backend: `backend.com`
- My front end: `frontend.com`
- Payment request from front end to backend: `backend.com/pay`
- Response url of the payment gateway to the backend: `backend/success`

I want to update the database and redirect my user to `frontend.com/success` with payment information when the payment is successful.
I am using Laravel for backend and vuejs for front end.

Comment: Redirect is not handle by server if your using client  side language  you can only redirect in client side base on server response

Answer (score 0):

After you send your POST request to the backend and receive a valid response, you can use Vue Router to redirect the user to the success page using `$router.push('/success')`

Comment: I am not getting response from my backend to my front end. I am getting response from a third party payment gateway to my backend. I need to process data in the backend and then redirect the user to the front end success route with some data.

Comment: How long does this payment API and processing step take? If it takes an unreasonable amount of time, I would not recommend increasing the timeout for the request made by the front end. Instead, I would recommend that the frontend makes a request every minute to poll the status of the payment until it is successful.